# URL rewrite using mod rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

Is it possible to do the following in a rewrite?

Given this url,

http://www.stockportovenrepairs.co.uk/spares/cda/cooker-oven/cd200ss/element-12345/12/

I currently rewrite this part 
`cda/cooker-oven/cd200ss/element-12345/12/` to 
`url=cda/cooker-oven/cd200ss/element-12345/12/` with QSA.

This works fine, but what would suit my situation better is if I could rewrite it to:

```
url=cda;cooker-oven;cd200ss;element-12345;12;
```

i.e. swap the forward slashes to semicolons, then append it to a querystring. Is this even possible with mod-rewrite, and do you have any pointers if it is?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mod-rewrite in Apache, try backreferences (assuming the url will have a known number of segments or a set format). Something like

```
RewriteRule /spares/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ http://host/something.do?url=$1;$2;$3;$4;$5; [NE]
```

This should rewrite your example as

```
http://host/something.do?url=cda;cooker-oven;cd200ss;element-12345;12;
```

which looks like what you want.

Edit: To prevent the semicolons from being escaped you'd need to add the [NE] directive as above.

Comment: Hi Thank You for your answer, yes it looks like it will suit my needs, the only thing i wasnt clear on is , the number of segments wil be 1, 2, 3 or 4. can i still impliment this

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you would need to do separate rewrite rules for each possible number of segments. As far as I know, there isn't a substitution directive to replace the slashes with semicolons, either.